# VHDL: TextIO, End of Line, Hread

Tags: vhdl

```
process

  variable vGoodRead      : boolean := true;

  while (vGoodRead = true) loop         -- read till end of line.

      hread (vLineIn, vInData, vGoodRead);
      ........
  end loop;

  vGoodRead := true;  -- cos at End of line, it turns false

end process;
```

I am using this code, to read in Hex values. 
There are multiple (and different no of) hex values on a single line.

This code works, provided all hex values on the line/s are correct.

My problem is, I have not been able to figure out, how to detect a case, when there is an incorrect input value, somewhere within the line. 
I.e. there is FO (f, cap O) versus F0 (f, zero). The latter being valid, while the first is invalid.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a pure programming question totally unrelated to electronics. So it is off-topic. If you want a good answer, post your real code in a forum dedicated to programming questions. Posting pseudo-code can be OK for discussing algorithms, but you are talking about error trapping. So you should post the real code (but not here).

Comment: Oh, I see. It is VHDL. My apologies. I am not familiar with VHDL. I mistook the actual code for pseudo-code. Perhaps since HW engineers use VHDL this is on-topic after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are characters remaining in the line when you detect vGoodRead as false, then the following will print the number of characters and print the actual characters that are left in the line:

```
  if vLineIn'length > 0 then 
    write(OUTPUT, "Number characters remaining in line: " & 
                  to_string(vLineIn'length) & LF) ;
    write(OUTPUT, "Actual characters are: " & vLineIn.all & LF) ; 
  end if ;
```

Comment: Oh..so vLineIn'length actually decrements, as the hread procedure is called, recursively?  In that case, I could use vLineIn'length = 0, as the end-of-line condition in my code, correct? In the code, I am already noting the line number. So, if vGoodRead is false, before EOL, then I know the line number. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! I used    if vLineIn'length = 0 as my EOL condition. Then using vLineNumber in my code, I am able to know of line with bad Hex numbers.